# how I can creat function checks if the variable is a punctuation marks that must return 1?

Tags: c++

```
   #include<iostream.h>

 int puncmarks(){

 char j;

 cin>>j;

 for( ;j=='!'||'"'||'#'||'$'||'%'||'&'||'()'||'*'||'+'||','||'- '||'.'||'/'||':'||';'||'<'||'='||'>'||'?'||'@'||'['||'\'||']'||'^'||'_'||'`'||'{'||'}'||'~'||'.'||')'; )
 return 1;
 return 0;

 main(){

    cout<<puncmarks()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: what is the for loop supposed to do? To check `if` a condition is satisfied, you would typically use `if`

Comment: Char is 1 character, just use switch (j) or add those to array then with for loop check all if they fit the regex.

Comment: `if (std::ispunct(j))`?.  Also, you should never, in a real-life program, assume what the punctuation characters are.  That's the job of `ispunct()`.

Comment: you can use [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Comment: I do not understand pleas anyone solve it without if (std::ispunct(j))?

Comment: even thous ispunct() checks if a character is classified as punctuation by a locale he is still learning and should try to solve it himself.. link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct

Comment: @DressyFiddle The solution is `ispunct()`.  Anything else is shoddy C++ coding and practice.